# Replace \n with \n' '

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file like this:

```
$ cat t.py 
'a\nb\n'
```

From within the file, with the cursor positioned on the first line, I would like to use `:s/` to get to

```
'a\n'
'b\n'
```

How can I do that? I have tried

```
:s/\\n/\n''
```

but that ends up with

```
'a^@''b^@'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this substitution in `vim`:

```sh
:%s/\(\\n\)\([^']\)/\1'\r'\2/g
```

**Explanation:**

- `%s/`: Substitution start
- `\(\\n\)`: Match literal `\n` and capture in group #1
- `\([^']\)`: Match a character that is not `'` and capture in group #2
- `/\1'\r'\2/`: Substitute with back-reference #1 + `'` + line-break + `'` + back-reference #2

**Substitution Result:**

```
'a\n'
'b\n'
```

---

Or you can use **very magic** regex in `vim` and avoid all the escaping:

```sh
%s/\v(\\n)([^'])/\1'\r'\2/g
```

Comment: Legend, thanks! I had to do this for quite a few lines of code in quite a few files so this really helped